Fill added rows based on a table breakdown
I have a .csv file that needs to be built semi regularly.
It has a parent prize with a total value and subprizes under it that equal the parent prize amount based on a breakdown table for each value.
I got to the point where new rows for subprizes are added based on the number of subprizes needed.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to fill those rows with the data I need based on the breakdown. I currently have the breakdown values in column F under Description but I'm not sure if this is the best way to get VBA to recognize which subprizes need to be added.
Example of Parent Prize List:

Table Breakdown of Values:

Formula to pull out breakdowns (Column L):
It's to make it easier to read since adding the subprizes is a manual process.
=TRIM(IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",$B$1&"x"&B2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",$C$1&"x"&C2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",$D$1&"x"&D2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",$E$1&"x"&E2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",$F$1&"x"&F2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",$G$1&"x"&G2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(H2),"",$H$1&"x"&H2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(I2),"",$I$1&"x"&I2)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(J2),"",$J$1&"x"&J2))

Subprizes to be added to new rows:

VBA Code to add rows:
Sub InsertRowsIf()
Dim lr As Long, R As Range, i As Long
lr = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set R = Range("G1", "G" & lr)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = R.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(R.Cells(i, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(R.Cells(i, 1)) Then
        R.Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(R.Cells(i, 1).Value).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

What Final Product Should Look Like:

Once the rows are added, I need to see:
$35 has one row with the $15 subprize and one with $20.
$40 has two rows of $20 and so on.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

I'm trying to add the MD tables but the post ends up too long. I'll see what else I can do to get that in there.

Paste code into a blank workbook to run as a demo.
Sub InsertRows()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add 30, Array(20, 10)
        .Add 35, Array(20, 15)
        .Add 40, Array(20, 20)
        .Add 45, Array(25, 20)
        .Add 55, Array(50, 5)
        .Add 60, Array(50, 10)
        .Add 65, Array(50, 15)
    End With
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar, prize As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        ' set up test data
        .Cells.Clear
        For r = 2 To 11
           .Cells(r, "E") = (r - 1) * 5
        Next
    
        ' get last row
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        ' scan up the sheet
        For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
           prize = .Cells(r, "E")
           .Cells(r, 1) = "$" & prize & " PRIZE"
           
           ' does this value need multiple lines
           If dict.exists(prize) Then
                ar = dict(prize)
           Else
                ar = Array(prize)
           End If
           
           ' insert rows
           For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
               .Rows(r + 1).Insert
               .Cells(r + 1, 1) = "$" & ar(i) & " PRIZE"
               n = n + 1
           Next
        Next
    
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows inserted", vbInformation
End Sub

